# Sharepoint2013 list item filter

Tags: sharepoint-2013

My requirement is I have to submit records into a list/lib with attachments and that record can be tag to category field they can be multiple for a single item.

i.e. An  item A can be tag to tag to category X or can be cat X,Y(multiple category can be)

My requirement it user can also filter these record in list/lib on the basis of category tagged.
i.e. if an item A is tagged with cat X,Y it should be show in both cat when we filter.

What approach i should i use in Sharepoint 2013?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the taxonomy to achieve this behaviour. Generate Term sets and terms in it and use them to tag your List Item.

You didnt provide the details about how you are searching the data? by your code or the OOTB sharepoint search ?

Thanks